# Varying modal content based on trigger with input: radio and checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Net mvc4 in this project. I got a problem in my javascript where the 
`modal.find('modal-body input:radio[name=require_attachment][id=' + attachment+ ']').prop('checked', true);`

It does not function properly. I also tried the jquery `filter` function:

`modal.find('modal-body input:radio[name=require_attachment]').filter(['value=' + attachment+ '']).prop('checked', true);`

Which has the same result, not working.

In my modal `button` that has data-* on with.e.g. `data-attachment`, I want to display it as a radio `checked` whether what value it return to the content of my modal.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"
        data-toggle="modal"
        data-target="#Update_COA_Codes"
        data-code="@item.code"
        data-attachment="@item.require_attachment"             
        data-status="@item.status"
        data-description="@item.description">Edit</button>
```

Inside my jquery script:

```
$('#Update_COA_Codes').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {   
  var button = $(event.relatedTarget)
  var attachment = button.data('attachment');
  //... other code here

  var modal = $(this);
  modal.find('modal-body input:radio[name= require_attachment]')
       .filter(['value=' + attachment + ''])
       .prop('checked', true);
});
```

HTML modal-body

```
<div class="row top-buffer">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <label><span class="red">*</span>Needs Attachments?</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <input type="radio" name="require_attachment" value="true"> Yes
    <input type="radio" name="require_attachment" value="false"> No
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm not sure if this is the correct way of doing it. I'm open for any suggestions, thank you.

Comment: Place a little dot before `modal-body` in your JS code and everything will be fine ;)